# Vulkan: Device Lost during Buffer Copy

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm having really hard time with a submitting a buffer copy command, in a way that doesn't make any sense to me. I'm getting a "Device Lost" error from the validation layer when I try to copy from a staging buffer to a device local buffer. What's really confusing about it is that it's only happening when I call the copy function in specific ways.

Here's the code:

Buffer.cpp

```
#include "Buffer.h"

namespace vkr
{
    Buffer::Buffer() : buffer(VK_NULL_HANDLE), size(0) {}

    Buffer::Buffer(
        const VmaAllocator & _allocator,
        const vk::DeviceSize bufferSize,
        const vk::BufferUsageFlags usage,
        const VmaMemoryUsage memoryUsageFlags
    ) :
        size(bufferSize)
    {
        vk::BufferCreateInfo bufferInfo = {};
        bufferInfo.size = size;
        bufferInfo.usage = usage;
        bufferInfo.sharingMode = vk::SharingMode::eExclusive;

        VmaAllocationCreateInfo allocInfo = {};
        allocInfo.usage = memoryUsageFlags;

        auto vanillaBufferInfo = (VkBufferCreateInfo)bufferInfo;

        vmaCreateBuffer(_allocator, &vanillaBufferInfo, &allocInfo, &buffer, &allocation, nullptr);
    }

    Buffer::Buffer(Buffer && otherBuffer)
    {
        buffer = otherBuffer.buffer;
        allocation = otherBuffer.allocation;
        size = otherBuffer.size;

        otherBuffer.buffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        otherBuffer.allocation = VmaAllocation();
        otherBuffer.size = 0;
    }

    Buffer & Buffer::operator=(Buffer && otherBuffer)
    {
        if (this != &otherBuffer) {
            buffer = otherBuffer.buffer;
            allocation = otherBuffer.allocation;
            size = otherBuffer.size;

            otherBuffer.buffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
            otherBuffer.allocation = VmaAllocation();
            otherBuffer.size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Buffer::operator vk::Buffer() const
    {
        return vk::Buffer(buffer);
    }

    Buffer::operator VkBuffer() const
    {
        return buffer;
    }

    void Buffer::copyInto(const VmaAllocator & _allocator, const void* dataSrc)
    {
        void* mappedData;
        vmaMapMemory(_allocator, allocation, &mappedData);
        memcpy(mappedData, dataSrc, (size_t)size);
        vmaUnmapMemory(_allocator, allocation);
    }

    void Buffer::copyInto(const VmaAllocator & _allocator, const void* dataSrc, const size_t newSize)
    {
        void* mappedData;

        vmaMapMemory(_allocator, allocation, &mappedData);
        memcpy(mappedData, dataSrc, newSize);
        vmaUnmapMemory(_allocator, allocation);
    }

    void Buffer::destroy(const VmaAllocator & _allocator)
    {
        vmaDestroyBuffer(_allocator, buffer, allocation);
    }
}
```

Staged Buffer:

```
#include "StagedBufferFactory.h"


namespace vkr
{
    namespace StagedBufferFactory
    {
        vkr::Buffer create(
            vk::Device & device,
            vk::CommandPool & commandPool,
            vk::Queue & graphicsQueue,
            const vk::BufferUsageFlags usageFlags,
            const vk::DeviceSize size,
            const void * dataSrc,
            const VmaAllocator & _allocator
        )
        {
            // Staging buffer that we load the data onto that's visible to our CPU
            vk::BufferUsageFlags stagingUsageFlags = vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferSrc;
            vkr::Buffer stagingBuffer{ _allocator, size, stagingUsageFlags, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_ONLY };
            stagingBuffer.copyInto(_allocator, &dataSrc, (size_t)size);

            // This is our buffer located on our GPU, inaccessible to our CPU
            vk::BufferUsageFlags gpuBufferUsageFlags = vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferDst | usageFlags;
            vkr::Buffer gpuBuffer{ _allocator, size, gpuBufferUsageFlags, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY };

            copyBuffer(device, commandPool, graphicsQueue, stagingBuffer, gpuBuffer);

            stagingBuffer.destroy(_allocator);

            return gpuBuffer;
        }

        void copyBuffer(
            vk::Device & device,
            vk::CommandPool & commandPool,
            vk::Queue & graphicsQueue,
            vkr::Buffer & stagingBuffer,
            vkr::Buffer & gpuBuffer
        )
        {
            vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
            allocInfo.level = vk::CommandBufferLevel::ePrimary;
            allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
            allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

            vk::CommandBuffer commandBuffer;
            device.allocateCommandBuffers(&allocInfo, &commandBuffer);

            vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
            beginInfo.flags = vk::CommandBufferUsageFlagBits::eOneTimeSubmit;

            commandBuffer.begin(&beginInfo);

            vk::BufferCopy copyRegion = {};
            copyRegion.srcOffset = 0;
            copyRegion.dstOffset = 0;
            copyRegion.size = stagingBuffer.size;
            commandBuffer.copyBuffer(stagingBuffer.buffer, gpuBuffer.buffer, 1, &copyRegion);

            commandBuffer.end();

            vk::SubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
            submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
            submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

            // Create fence to ensure that the command buffer has finished executing
            vk::FenceCreateInfo fenceInfo{};
            vk::Fence fence = device.createFence(fenceInfo);

            // Submit to the queue
            graphicsQueue.submit(1, &submitInfo, fence);
            graphicsQueue.waitIdle();
            //device.waitForFences({ fence }, true, 100000000000);
            device.destroyFence(fence);

            device.free(commandPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Buffer Creation:

```
void HelloTriangleApplication::createIndexBuffer()
{
    vk::DeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(indices[0]) * indices.size();

    //// Staging buffer that we load the data onto that's visible to our CPU
    vk::BufferUsageFlags stagingUsageFlags = vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferSrc;
    vkr::Buffer stagingBuffer{ vulkanAllocator, bufferSize, stagingUsageFlags, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_ONLY };

    stagingBuffer.copyInto(vulkanAllocator, indices.data());

    //// This is our buffer located on our GPU, inaccessible to our CPU
    vk::BufferUsageFlags indexUsageFlags = vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferDst | vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eIndexBuffer;
    indexBuffer = vkr::Buffer{ vulkanAllocator, bufferSize, indexUsageFlags, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY };

    vkr::StagedBufferFactory::copyBuffer(device, commandPool, graphicsQueue, stagingBuffer, indexBuffer);

    stagingBuffer.destroy(vulkanAllocator);
}
```

So this code works without issue... but if I try using my `vkr::StagedBuffer::create` function (which calls this exact code as far as I can tell) the program doesn't work. I get a black screen (instead of my rainbow-colored rectangle) and occasionally the validation layer tells me that "Device Lost"

```
void HelloTriangleApplication::createIndexBuffer()
{
    vk::DeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(indices[0]) * indices.size();

    indexBuffer = vkr::StagedBufferFactory::create(device, commandPool, graphicsQueue, vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eIndexBuffer, bufferSize, indices.data(), vulkanAllocator);
}
```

I'm tearing my hair out, and I definitely don't understand why this would *ever* be the case.

Comment: `&dataSrc` is the address of the local stack variable, you probably meant `dataSrc` instead, So your index buffer is full of junk, which may or may not be the cause of your issue. It'll definitely cause the black screen, but I'm not so sure about the validation error. It might be a bug in the driver when handling out-of-bounds indices?

Comment: Oh my god this is almost definitely the problem. I'll try it out tonight and confirm. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank pointed out, this was all due to a syntax error in my `vkr::StagedBufferFactory::create` code that's posted above. I was accidentally taking a pointer of the passed in `dataSrc` pointer, leading to me trying to fill my VkBuffer with garbage.

Comment: Unfortunately, such problems are quite common and hard to spot. If there are problems similar to the ones described by You, in most cases it is a bug in code - uninitialized variable, passing a pointer to a temporary variable etc.

Comment: If this issue is resolved, please mark this as the correct answer to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: A good mechanism to resolve this kind of error is to avoid `void*` as a function parameter, and instead use templates to allow you to pass in typed data _references_ instead of pointers.  It also tends to lead to cleaner code on the calling side.

Comment: Thanks for that advice Jherico, I'll look into that!